# Cocos2d - Easing functions not running animation

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having some issues with the CCEase* action wrappers. I can run an action with no easing and it performs as expected, but when I add easing, the animation doesn't run and it just 'pops' to the end of the action after the delay.

I can use
`[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:position]`
which works well, but when I try to add easing it causes the issue.

I have tried with various easing functions, running only one action, or running a sequence with easing on the internal actions but neither work

`[CCEaseOut actionWithAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:position]]` does not work for me.

They work for me in other parts of my app, but not everywhere. I am not doing anything discernibly different so I am at a loss.

Has anybody had any experience with this before? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the `rate` of the easing action in order for it to work, otherwise the action will pop as you described.

look at the [signature](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_ease_rate_action.html) of the methods of `CCEaseRateAction` class as some easing actions you are trying to use inherit from it. Use `actionWithAction:rate:` method (or init...)

Comment: Thank you - I had assumed that it was provided with a default value like `[CCEaseElastic* ]`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this may be it will work

```
id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(100,100)];
id ease = [CCEaseOut actionWithAction:action rate:2];
[sprite runAction: ease];
```